# Problem with Bing.AdvancedSearchBox helper method

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, html-helper

Is anyone else experiencing problems with the Bing helper in Microsoft.Web.Helpers?

The Bing.AdvancedSearchBox helper method tried to load the following javascript file but throws a 404 error. The script is http://www.bing.com/bootstrap.js

Has anyone else experience the same problem? So far there has not been any updates to the microsoft-web-helpers package in Nuget. Any information is greatly appreciated.

Thanks, 
Diego.

**UPDATE 5/1/2011**

I found the following official statement...
I wonder when Micorsoft will release an update to Microsoft.Web.Helper to remove the deprecated functionality.

Note: Bing team at Microsoft announced that they will be shutting down siteowner service on April 4th. This will prevent you to use the AdvancedSearchBox feature of Bing on your website/blog or web applications. Here is the quote from Bing's official blog:

As of April 4th, 2011 we will discontinue support for the bing.com/siteowner functionality. If you continue to leverage the feature after this date (April 4th, 2011), users who attempt to query in the search box will be redirected to a 404 page. This means that you will need to move to the Bing API in order to continue to receive web or site search results from us. We have decided to take this step for two reasons.

First, the tool has not been getting a lot of use and while we have some very loyal customers on it, we believe we can provide you better alternatives in the future as we free up resources.

Second, the functionality available through bing.com/siteowner can be replicated with the Bing search API and so it feels a bit redundant.

As has become customary, we will give you a window to migrate off and ask us any questions you may have about this change. We will also provide reminders as we get closer to April 4th. Thank you so much for your support.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like something has changed on the bing servers and this script no longer exists.